# How to get the current iScroll position?

Tags: cordova, iscroll

First, I really sorry for my poor english...

Now I use iScroll to make my table scrolling,I want to get the current scroller's position.

For example

```
var myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');



    <div id="wrapper">
         <table id="myTable">
                        <thead > 
                            <tr> 
                                <th>first name</th>
                                <th>last name</th>
                                <th>country</th>
                                <th >sex<br/>Time</th>
                            </tr> 
                        </thead> 
                        <tbody>
                           .
                           .
                           .
                           .
                          <tr id="last-tr">
                             <td>...</td>
                             <td>...</td>
                             <td>...</td>
                             <td>...</td>
                          </tr>
         </table>
    </div>
```

Now I want to bind some methods in a event, this event will be triggered when my scroller scroll to the last-tr.
Can anyone help??
I will be grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can say that u want to bind when the first row of the last tr comes in the viewport..

While using iscroll u can bind events on the function '**onScrollMove**'

If u havent already, add this to the iscroll wrapper js -

```
options.onScrollMove = function(){
      that.triggerHandler('onScrollMove', [this]);
    };
```

Then bind your event handler to listen to onScrollMove. This code goes into the event handler-

```
var cont =$('#wrapper');
var docViewBottom = $(cont).scrollTop() + $(cont).height();
    var itemOffset = $('tr#last-tr').offset();
    if(itemOffset){
        //it means that the last tr is in view..  bind events here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!But the 'onScrollMove' event not trigger when touch over

Comment: When I touch over the screen, the scroller still scrolling, but it already not trigger the 'onScrollMove' event.